# How to take conditional actions on bas64 encoded trigger output in Power Automate Flow?

Tags: azure-eventhub, power-automate

My trigger is an Event Hub stream from Azure IoT Central telemetry data.

I need to conditionally run an action based on the keys in the Content from the Event Hub trigger.

The Content output from Event Hub trigger is base64 encoded.

If I use Content in an Action like Post Message to Teams, it is decoded and looks fine.
The content is NOT decoded when I try to use it in a Conditional Action, or if I instantiate a variable first. There is no base64ToString() in the expressions for Power Automate. Power Automate doc's say they will automatically decode for you (and no they don't).

Anyone have a working base64 decode method with Power Automate or another workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This just does not work in Power Automate.

It works fine in Logic Apps.

I just rebuilt everything in Logic Apps and it works great.